# Can we perform concurrent read and write operation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I ha have a query regarding MongoDB. I read the documentation but did not get a clear idea about that, so asking here. I have one collection on which I need to perform 24/7 read and write operations from different sources. So the query is May we perform concurrent read and write operations on the same collection at the same time? If no then what is the alternative or what's the main reason behind that .

I have some python crons which perform R/W Operations on collections at the same time I have some node side backend API that performs R/W operations on the same collection so will it cause any issue? Currently, this all is performing on the MySQL side but now as per client requirement, I need to move to MongoDB from MySQL. So please help me get clear about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [FAQ: Concurrency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)

> MongoDB uses reader-writer locks that allow concurrent readers shared
> access to a resource, such as a database or collection.
>
> In addition to a shared (S) locking mode for reads and an exclusive
> (X) locking mode for write operations, intent shared (IS) and intent
> exclusive (IX) modes indicate an intent to read or write a resource
> using a finer granularity lock. When locking at a certain granularity,
> all higher levels are locked using an intent lock.

And regarding [Wired Tiger engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#document-level-concurrency)

> For most read and write operations, WiredTiger uses optimistic
> concurrency control. WiredTiger uses only intent locks at the global,
> database and collection levels.

Current default mongodb engine is `WiredTiger` so if you use it - you're OK. To check the engine execute this `db.serverStatus().storageEngine`